# Elements not displaying correctly in IE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a form in IE, but for some reason, the layout is broken as you can see from the picture. I have tried various fixes inc, clears, display:block options, but still the layout breaks. If this was in FF, I could use firebug to trace where it is breaking but IE has no such debug tool, hence the post. I would be grateful if someone could show me my error. Thanks

```
.adduserform label
        {

        display:block;
        width:130px;
        float:left;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:12px;
        padding: 4px 0 0 40px;
        z-index:1000;
        clear:both;
        line-height: 20px;

        }

.adduserform select
        {

        width: 130px;
        float:left
        font-family:Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        outline:none;
        margin-top: 5px;
        clear:both;
        }

        <div id="coname">
        <div id="AUSR_address"></div>
                <dl>
                <dt>
                    <label for="AUSR_name" class="opt">Full Name:</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input id="AUSR_name" name="AUSR_name" type="text" size="32" maxlength="128" value = "" />
                </dd>
              </dl>
              </div>
```

[image: IE incorrect layout]

+++SOLUTION+++

```
div#coname {

    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @martin. oopps..sorry doing it know. thanks

Comment: Some versions of IE do have a similar tool to Firebug, try pressing F12

Comment: @shane I have tried that but found it more of a hindurance than a helpful tool. Every time you try something, just keeps refreshing the browser. What we need is firebug for IE. I know there is a cut down version so may check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE has developer toolbar. If you press F12 it should bring it up and should help you find your issue. You can also use it to view your pages in different IE version modes.

Comment: John I am not too familiar with IE Toolbar, apart from the fact it seems to take forever to update itself. How could I use it to help with my issue? Thanks

Comment: It should pretty much the same as firebug. If you use the element selector you can use the attributes section to add styles to your elements so you can preview what Changes look like.  With your code I'd be tempted to put your labels and inputs inside a dive each and have a float: left and clear both on the label div.

Answer (score 1):

I would start out by making sure you have a doctype at the top like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Without specifying a doctype, IE reverts to quirks mode and things can get a little ugly. An example above is for HTML5, but there are quite a few more. For a full list of possible doctypes, refer here: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Ironically, there is a website called http://www.quirksmode.org/ which keeps track of various compatibility issues across browsers.  Might find it helpful in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

#### [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359)

- Newer Versions (press F12)
- Older Versions (go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) and download)

#### [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

*Many of the features in FF's firebug can be extended to other browsers using this bookmarklet*

---

*Do you have an online version of this page that we could actually see?  There could be many reasons, which could be width-related to something messed up with the block model.*

Comment: vol7ron See solution I have managed to get it working with. Thanks

Comment: and that is why you did not have enough info.  that is also a misuse of the `dl`, `dt`, `dd` tag.